# Express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option. Config not working even though it is set

Tags: node.js, express, config

```
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const config = require('config');
var MemoryStore = require('memorystore')(session);


module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(cors());
    app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
    app.use(
        session({
            saveUninitialized: false,
            cookie: { maxAge: 86400000 },
            store: new MemoryStore({
                checkPeriod: 86400000
            }),
            resave: false,
            secret: config.get('sStorage')
        })
    );
    app.use('/api/users', users);
}
```

I looked at all the existing solutions provided but it's still not working for me. I'm getting this error

express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option.

It's working properly when i rewrite the code like this

```
  secret: config.get('sStorage') || "testsecret"
```

I checked my env variable to see if sStorage is set and showing it's defined. Why is the env variable not getting loaded here in this specific case using config module?

Comment: So what does ```console.log(`config value for sStorage is ${config.get('sStorage')}`)``` show you, if you run it before module.exports?

Comment: For console.log(config.get('sStorage')) I'm getting the env variable I have set for this case.....

Comment: then `config.get('sStorage') || "testsecret"` will not actually make a difference, and it's [mcve] time - not so much "to show us", but for you to remove as much code as possible until you truly have the barest of minimum code that still has this problem.

Comment: This was a great suggestion. I was able to reduce the code and figure out the mistake. Thanks

Comment: Nice! Then I shall vote to close this question as "no longer a problem", unless the real problem was still related and there's a good answer you can write to explain what went wrong that you think will benefit future visitors =)